# GNOME Dia UI layout

Tags: dia

I'm starting to use Dia as a Linux diagramming solution. I'm using 0.97 (which comes with Ubuntu Oneiric). I saw images of its user interface (UI) showing the [whole application with tabs](http://live.gnome.org/Dia/Screenshots?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=dia-0.97-integrated-ui.png) instead of [the classic GIMP UI](http://softwareforlearning.tki.org.nz/var/tki-sfl/storage/images/media/images/screenshot-of-dia-software-in-use/8490-1-eng-NZ/Screenshot-of-Dia-software-in-use.jpg) (Main window and one window per diagram).

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the commandline parameter --integrated to start the tabbed interface:

dia --integrated